# Differential Equations: Laplace Transform to Solve Integral Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm working through some lectures notes on Differential Equations, and in the Laplace Transform section I've encountered the following problem:

**Problem**

Find a solution to

$$x'(t)+\int^{t}_{0}(t-s)x(s)ds=t+\frac{1}{2}t^2+\frac{1}{24}t^4$$

I'm not really sure how we can apply the Laplace transform here; any assisstance would be greatly appreciated. Regards as always, MM.

Comment: The Laplace transform of a convolution $f\star g$ is the product of the Laplace transforms of $f$ and $g$. So ${\cal L} \int_0^t g(t-s) f(s) ds=F(s)G(s)$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Here then, are we to assume that $g$ is the identity map (as $g(t-s)=t-s$)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking the Laplace transform of the left hand side, 
using the  [convolution formula](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ConvolutionIntegrals.aspx)  on the integral (note the integral is $f\star g$ where $f $ is the identity function and and $g=x$):
$${\cal  L} \Bigl( x'(t)+\int^{t}_{0}(t-s)x(s)ds\Bigr) = s X(s)-x(0) + {1\over s^2}\cdot X(s).
$$

Taking the Laplace transform of the right hand side:
$$
{\cal L}\Bigl( t+\frac{1}{2}t^2+\frac{1}{24}t^4 \Bigr)=
{1\over s^2}+{1\over 2}{2\over s^3}+{1\over 24}\cdot{24\over s^5}.
$$
So, we have:
$$
 s X(s)-x(0) + {1\over s^2}\cdot X(s)=
{1\over s^2}+ {1\over s^3}+ {1\over s^5}.
$$

Now solve for $X(s)$ and then take the inverse transform to find $x(t)$.